# Solr search from beginning of string

Tags: solr, lucene, sunspot

I need to boost results which are found from beginning of string. For Example i have to countries: Egypt and Seychelles.

User types "e" in a text field and solr response will be:

- S**e**ych**e**ll**e**s
- **E**gypt

But as you can see "Egypt" starts with "e". And i need this result to be boosted up:

- **E**gypt
- S**e**ych**e**ll**e**s

Any other results should be scored as usual. Is there any kind of special tokenizers/serializers? Or may be special characters in SolrQuery syntax?

**UPD:**

Part of my `schema.xml` which describes text field type:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="20" side="front" />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: I assume you're using an an NGramTokenizer, or some such, then?

Comment: @femtoRgon you're right. I updated my question so you can look at my text field type configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by using `EdgeNGramFilterFactory` instead of `NGramFilterFactory`:

```
<fieldType name="text_start_end" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PositionFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="20" side="front" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```